# Convert datetime to date into singleordefault method

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make a system that saves the date & time but first I want to check if the operation hadn't been done in the same day. I created a function in my sql schema named TruncateTime as following :

```
Create FUNCTION TruncateTime(@dateValue DateTime) RETURNS date
AS BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(date, @dateValue)
END
```

And to check the date in my c# script I wrote :

```
p = dc.pointages.SingleOrDefault(x => 
    x.userid.Equals(user_id) && 
    EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date_pointage)== today.Date );
```

The exeption thrown is :

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code

I tried so many ways i am now confused.

Comment: Instead of trying to get data from user defined function, try to get data from stored procedure.

Comment: What's the innerException message?

Comment: Always post the full exception. Catch the exception, post `ex.ToString()`. Then be sure to get rid of the try/catch block you added!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use custom methods when doing linq queries against a dbset, but you can make it into a list first, and then compare it. Note that you get all records when doing that though, instead of filtering in the database.

```
p = dc.pointages
      .Where(x => x.userid.Equals(user_id))
      .ToList() // this will enable you to call custom methods in SingleOrDefault
      .SingleOrDefault(x => 
         EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date_pointage)== today.Date );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get away with using the built-in date comparison of a DateTime object, something like:

```
p = dc.pointages.SingleOrDefault(x => 
    x.userid.Equals(user_id) && 
    x.date_pointage.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinqPad i created sample for you:

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>(){
        new DateTime(2015,1,1,0,0,1),
        new DateTime(2015,1,1,0,1,1),
        new DateTime(2015,1,2,0,2,2),
        new DateTime(2015,1,2,0,3,3),
        new DateTime(2015,1,3,0,4,4),
        new DateTime(2015,1,3,0,5,5),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,8,7,6),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,9,7,7),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,10,8,8),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,11,9,9),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,12,10,10),
        new DateTime(2015,1,9,13,11,11)
        };

var qry = dates.Where(x=>x.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")==new DateTime(2015,1,9).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));

qry.Dump();
```

Results:

```
2015-01-09 08:07:06 
2015-01-09 09:07:07 
2015-01-09 10:08:08 
2015-01-09 11:09:09 
2015-01-09 12:10:10 
2015-01-09 13:11:11
```

Note: you need to change it to your needs ;)